# How to check which TLS version is used by the python services in production

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, tls1.2, tls1.3

Since the AWS API endpoints will now require TLS 1.2 as a minimum protocol level, I wanted to check if all my production services written in python `3.6` or python `3.10` are using TLS version `>=1.2`.

What did I try?

Tried all other Stack Overflow threads, Github issues, and some websites, but encountered some or the other issues.

My Question -

Since there are a bunch of production services to check and it takes significant time to build the artifacts, I need a simple and a quick method.

Also, it will be good if I can make this method as part of my build workflow so that we can enforce usage of only updated packages in python services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the following steps manually but these can also be automated by making them part of your build workflow -

1. Make the virtual environment on local machine.
2. Install the requirements for the production service using `pip instal -e .`
3. Activate the virtual env, and type -

`python3 -c "import requests; print(requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check', verify=False).json()['tls_version'])"`

4. If the output is `TLS 1.2` or `TLS 1.3`, you are safe.

References

[1] https://www.calazan.com/how-to-check-if-your-python-app-supports-tls-12/